# How to design a within subjects structural equation model

Tags: r, repeated-measures, structural-equation-modeling, lavaan

I'm *very* new to SEM/Path analysis. I'd like to know how to design/visualize a within-subjects SEM/Path analysis. For example, suppose I'm measuring a path from a cognitive measure X that should impact vocabulary and grammar (which share some variance) that, in turn, should impact a linguistic outcome Y. However, the same participants performed tests in English and tests in another language (vocabulary, grammar and linguistic_outcome). I want to know how would I

- **1:** See if the imaginated path is different for the English and the other language tasks. For example, this would answer a RQ such as " *do the relantionships between cognition -> grammar -> linguistic outcome and cognitiion -> vocabulary -> linguistic outcome" vary as a function of the language being tested* " ? " *Are the relantionships weaker or stronger for either language* " ?
- **2:** How would a single model be different from testing a model such as in the picture below for either language separatedly? (ps: In terms of terminology, this would be a path analysis, right, no a SEM)?
- **note:** I would hypothetize that the cognitive measure only has indirect effects on the linguistic outcome, but I included the direct c path just to rule it out. I guess that's the right approach, right? test it, and then stick to the more parsimonious model?

I have a few guesses. I suppose that, in order to perform this, I would have to convert the participants scores into latent or composite ([I suppose "composite" is the adequate term here, right?](https://jslefche.github.io/sem_book/composite-variables.html#what-is-a-composite-variable)) variables, leading to something like this:

X = COGNITIVE MEASURE (only in one language) 
Comp_Voc = Vocabulary_Eng + Vocabulary_OtherLanguage 
Comp_Grammar = Grammar_Eng + Grammar_OtherLanguage 
Y Comp_Linguistic outcome = Linguistic_Out_Eng + Linguistic_Out_OtherLanguage

Ok. But **where do the 'LanguageOfTesting' variable goes** ? Am I looking at mediation? How and where should I include it in the design?

- The model would be something like this:

[image: path]

- I've seen some related materials on multigroup SEMs that helped a bit ([ex](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/554687/multi-group-sem-how-to-interpret-group-differences-given-weak-measurement-invar), [ex2](https://jslefche.github.io/sem_book/multigroup-analysis.html) , , [video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=FDV99B54BJQ)) and this question about a paired t-test ([ex4](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/117507/paired-samples-t-test-using-a-structural-equation-modeling-approach)). However, I wouldn't have two independent groups, but the same groups being tested twice in ENG and in the other language. I'm still confused. I'd really appreciate some help.

Ps:  I still haven't run the experiment, so I don't have the data just yet. I'm intending to use R's `lavaan`, so any tips on that would be useful as well

Answer (score 3):

In a repeated measures analysis, you have a measure per person.

Every measure is a variable in your model, if you have two measures (one for each language) then you have two variables in the model. (It's not absolutely clear to me what your null hypothesis is, so I'm not certain how you would do it.)

For example: A paired t-test, in SEM is: [image: Path diagram of paired t-test]

Can you draw a path diagram of your hypothesis?

Comment: Hi, @Jeremy Miles ! Thank you for your answer. So, H1 would be = "The path from COGNITIVE TASK -> GRAMMAR/VOCABULARY -> LINGUISTIC TASK VARY as a function of language" and, H0, in turn, "The path from COGNITIVE TASK -> GRAMMAR/VOCABULARY -> LINGUISTIC TASK" does not vary as a function of language, hence, the relantionship is the same for the performance in English and for the performance in the other language (which is what I believe that will happen)

Comment: I tried to design the path diagram, but I'm struggling with that. Can you give me a few more tips on that? I can say I have two main goals, first: "for both languages, I'll have indirect effects from cognition -> grammar/vocabulary -> linguistic outcome" (hence, the path doesn't vary as a function of lang") (here I believe I have to have a SEM with composite scores, right) and 2) "I believe that the direct effect of the cog task to grammar/vocab will be stronger for the other language than for Eng" (here, I believe I have to perform two separate path analyses, right? one for each language)

Comment: Mainly: 1) I believe that the path will be significant for both language's performances (I think here I have to use SEM with composite scores) (I think it's similar to a multigroup SEM, but my experiment will be within-subjects....) and 2) I believe that I'll have stronger relantions for the L2 (here I think I should test 2 path analysis separately? one for each lang) ? 3) I don't think there's gonna be a direct effect from cog -> linguistic, but I'll test anyway to rule it out 4) I think grammar and vocabulary will share some variance in explaining the linguistic outcome

Comment: So, I'll test if there's a path from 1) vocabulary -> linguistic outcome 2) grammar -> linguistic outcome 3) both voc and grammar to linguistic outcome and, then,  1) cognition -> vocabulary -> linguistic outcome 2) cognition -> grammar -> linguistic outcome 3) cognition -> grammar  and vocabulary -> linguistic outcome . Participants will only have 1 cognition score, but a grammar, a vocabulary and a linguistic for both languages. Is it clearer now?

Comment: You have two lingustic outcomes, so they can be two variables in the model. These can both have arrows pointing at them, and the magnitude of these effects can be compared.

Comment: Hi, @Jeremy Miles ! Why shouldn't I turn them into a composite score? (and the same with vocabulary and grammar) ?

Comment: Perhaps I don't understand but I thought you wanted to compare effects?

Comment: Hi, @Jeremy Miles ! I'm mostly interested in two things.  a) "does the path from vocabulary -> linguistic outcome 2) grammar -> linguistic outcome 3) both voc and grammar to linguistic outcome  vary as a function of the language being tested?" (for this, I think I should make a model with composite scores, right?) and b) "are the direct and indirect affects in the model stronger/weaker for English or for the other language?" (for this, I think I should perform 2 path analysis separatedly for each lang, right?)

Comment: I think I could use a multigroup model 'ish', but my scores will be within participants, the samples won't be independent, the same participants will perform the tests in the two languages

Comment: Yes, you shouldn't use a multiple group model.

Comment: I'm a bit confused because whether you use composite scores or latent variables isn't relevant to whether you do a multiple group model.

Comment: Hi, @Jeremy Miles ! See, I'm most struggling to visualize where the variable "Language" goes. Meaning: I want to check if  "the (possible) path from the cognitive measure -> vocabulary -> linguistic outcome" and the (possible) path from the cognitive measure -> grammar -> linguistic outcome" vary as a function of language

Comment: I suppose I should propose a model as such: "cognitive measure -> composite score of vocabulary (Eng + other lang scores) and grammar (Eng + other lang scores) -> composite score of linguistic outcome (Eng + other lang scores)" , right ? But where does the "lang" variable goes?

Comment: There's no lang variable in your description above.

Comment: Draw a path diagram, and it is easier to explain.

Comment: hi! So, I'm *trying* to draw it, but I cannot *visualize* it. So, I'm stuck. That's my biggest difficulty. I don't know where to put the lang variable, should it be a mediator before grammar and voc, for instance? The lang variable comes in in the moment that I have to test "he (possible) path from the cognitive measure -> vocabulary -> linguistic outcome" and the (possible) path from the cognitive measure -> grammar -> linguistic outcome" vary as a function of language". For example, in a simple multivariate regression, I'd have "Lang" dummy coded as 0 = Eng and 1 = the other

Comment: for example, supposing that I'd wanted to test if there was an effect of language on grammar in s imple regression, I'd do GRAMMAR ~ LANGUAGE (Eng + the other). I'm really struggling to convert this idea to the path model

Comment: just to remember: all participants (so, within-subj) will have 2 scores for grammar (Eng + the other lang), 2 for vocabulary (Eng + the other lang) and two scores for 2 linguistic tasks (Eng + other language) and I want to see if the indirect path I described in the previous commments cognitive measure -> gramar/vocab -> ling outcome vary as a function of language of testing

Comment: :) I'm kind of lazy, otherwise I'd do it. But you wrote: "cognitive measure -> composite score of vocabulary (Eng + other lang scores) and grammar (Eng + other lang scores) -> composite score of linguistic outcome (Eng + other lang scores). You can draw that?

Comment: Here's an example of a repeated measures t-test. https://posit.cloud/content/6121121 Notice how we get the same p-value. But there is no variable called 'group' in the model. Same (kind of ) thing.

Comment: Hi, @Jeremy Miles ! Thanks for the example, I'm trying to visualize it with ```lavaanPlot``` but I can't, I don't know why. I tried to do that, take a look: https://github.com/Larissa-Cury/SO_June

Comment: You have a variable called 'LANGUAGE (Eng or L2)' . Is that a variable in your data? Or is that two variables? (I don't use lavaan plot).

Comment: No, I don't have it, @Jeremy Miles.  I'm wondering if I should create it. For example, pivoting the participants scores into a column called 'VOCABULARY', for example, and a column called LANGUAGE (Categorical: Eng x Other)

Comment: oh, do you use another package or function to visualize your plots with ```lavaan``` ? I'm only aware of ```lavaan plot```

Comment: I just draw them, I've never seen a package that quite works well enough.